# EclipseLink 2.5.2: does @ReadOnly imply @Cacheable?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, readonly

In EclipseLink 2.5.2, if an `@javax.persistence.Entity` is annotated as `@org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.ReadOnly`, is there any benefit to also annotating it as `@javax.persistence.Cacheable`, or is `@Cacheable` automatically implied by `@ReadOnly`?

Thanks.